# No <Image> component and I get the <Image> component cannot contain children

Tags: react-native

This question has been asked but this scenario is different.
The entire error is: `Error: The <Image> component cannot contain children. If you want to render content on top of the image, consider using the <ImageBackground> component or absolute positioning.` Which is very self explanatory.  However it doesn't help me because I don't have an Image component in my code, I've check and nowhere is there an Image component being called.

The error being displayed is saying it's here:

```
This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:25)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
```

Here is my code for App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Expo from "expo";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import HomeScreen from "./src/HomeScreen/index.js";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      isReady: false
    };
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    // await Expo.Font.loadAsync({
    //   Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
    //   Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
    //   Ionicons: require("native-base/Fonts/Ionicons.ttf")
    // });
    this.setState({ isReady: true });
  }
  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    }
    return <HomeScreen />;
  }
}
```

HomeScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { StatusBar } from "react-native";
import { Container, Header, Title, Left, Icon, Right, Button, Body, Content, Text, Card, CardItem } from "native-base";

export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button
            transparent
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DrawerOpen")}>
            <Icon name="menu" />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
              <Title>HomeScreen</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
          </Header>
          <Content padder>
                <Card>
                  <CardItem>
                  <Body>
                    <Text>Chat App to talk someawesome people</Text>
                  </Body>
                  </CardItem>
                </Card>
                <Button full rounded dark
                    style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Chat")}>
                    <Text>Chat With People</Text>
                </Button>    
                <Button full rounded primary
                      style={{ marginTop: 10 }}
                      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Profile")}>
                      <Text>Goto Profiles</Text>
                </Button>
            </Content>
          </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

As you can see nowhere here are we calling an  Component which is the part I can't figure out.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I'm answering my own question for someone else who might encounter.
React Native gives the error that

```
This error is located at:
    in NavigationContainer (at App.js:25)
    in App (at withExpoRoot.js:22)
```

However this error is located in a file that is in a subcomponent in my case:
Sidebar.js

```
return (
  <Container>
    <Content>
    <Image
      source={{
        uri: "https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/raw/react-navigation/img/drawer-cover.png"
      }}
      style={{
        height: 120,
        alignSelf: "stretch",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center"
      }}>
      <Image
        square
        style={{ height: 80, width: 70 }}
        source={{
          uri: "https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase-KitchenSink/raw/react-navigation/img/drawer-cover.png"
        }}
      />
    </Image>
    <List
      dataArray={routes}
      renderRow={data => {
        return (
          <ListItem
            button
            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate(data)}>
            <Text>{data}</Text>
          </ListItem>
        );
      }}
      />
    </Content>
  </Container>
);
```

I then changed `<Image>` to `<ImageBackground>` and it works.